# Updating XML file with LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, linq

I am trying to update an existing XML file with linq.  Here is my code;

```
string myPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData) + "\\mySettings.xml";
XDocument cashierSettings = XDocument.Load(settingsPath);
var updateSettings = from c in cashierSettings.Elements("Settings")
     select c;
foreach (XElement x in updateSettings)
{
     x.Element("Setting1").SetValue("Hope this works");
}
cashierSettings.Save(settingsPath);
```

No error is given just not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: If you debug it, what is the value of `updateSettings.Count()`?  An easier way might be to use [Descendants()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.descendants(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: My guess `cashierSettings.Elements("Settings")` returns empty. Maybe `cashierSettings.Root.Elements("Settings")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An educated guess: you are loading the `XDocument` from `settingsPath` instead of `myPath`.

You are probably updating whatever file is `settingPath` but you expected to update `myPath`.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show us your `XML` structure but I think you need `Descandants` probably `Settings` are child element of `Root` or child element of something else, therefore `updateSetting` become empty.

```
var updateSettings = from c in cashierSettings.Descendants("Settings")
                     select c;
```